# Removing htmlescape from custom options in Magento. Which file displays custom options?

Tags: php, html, magento, e-commerce

I need to put HTML in the custom option labels for each product in my Magento store, but by default HTML isn't parsed by Magento when it is put into the custom options interface.  I'm assuming that there is something like "$this->htmlEscape()" in the file that displays custom options, and I'd like to remove it so that I can add HTML into my option labels.

I'm having difficulty finding the file in Magento that displays custom options so that I can remove this line.  Does anyone have any wisdom they can offer?

Thank you, I really appreciate the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look in template files that are located in /catalog/product/view/options/type/

You will find the `htmlEscape()` inside the first `<dt>` which encloses the option title.
Here is a test that I have done :

- Option input type: "Field"
- Option title:

  `<div class="block block-cart"><div class="block-title"><strong><span>My Stylish Option Title</span></strong></div></div>`
- Updated template
     file: catalog/product/view/options/type/**text**.phtml

Rendering:

[image: stylish option title]